# Forbidden Patterns policy with TFS 2012 and VS 2010

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2012, and a mixed environment of Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012.  I recently applied the TFS Power Tools Forbidden Patterns check-in policy to a project.  Check-ins seem to be working fine from VS 2012, but when we attempt to check in with VS 2010, we get an error loading the Forbidden Patterns policy.

It probably just needs to be installed or registered for VS 2010, but I am not sure how to do that.  (can I use an older version of TFS Power Tools? -- seems wrong because then we could have different logic for the same policy)?

Any idea how to address this?

Comment: Do you have TFS Power Tools 2010 installed on the machines using VS2010? I would expect that there was no change in logic of the policies, it's just referencing the new assemblies for TFS2012 and some customizations for compatibility.

Comment: Installing the TFS Powertools for 2010 did work, but it did worry me a little, as that is a different version of the dll.

Comment: Sure it is, the new one is referencing the TFS2012 assemblies (TeamExplorer), while the old version is referencing TFS2010 assemblies. The logic itself shouldn't be changed. So nothing to worry about.

Comment: @JMarsch You should post that as an answer to your own question as it is the answer to the problem and many will come across the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the version of Team Foundation Power Tools that matches the version of Visual Studio that you need the add-ons (like checkin policies) to work for.  However, if you try to install the shell extension for more than one version, the install will fail. It is suggested to install the shell extension for the latest version of TFS you are using and for other TFPT versions, uncheck that option during install.

[TFPT 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f)

[TFPT 2012](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f)

[TFPT 2010](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)